# My href link is removed due to JQuery Script

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

Can someone tell me why my table row href links are being removed when I add my JQuery script.  I added the URL to the html but when I add the script, the URL is removed.  Below is my table code:

```
 <table border="0">
           <tbody>
              <tr class="header">
                 <td>Header</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td><a href="http://www.google.com">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="header">
                 <td>Header</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">\x3C/script>');
</script>

<script language="javascript">

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("HideBrandingsuite");

function HideBrandingsuite()

{

document.getElementById('pageTitle').style.visibility = 'hidden';

} 
$('tr.header').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.header').css('display', function(i,v){
        return this.style.display === 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    });
});
</script>
```